# Native iOS Twitter post from Unity

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, native

I'm trying to implement the native iOS twitter account to unity. I found a code which uses the native social accounts via Xcode, and so I'm trying to make it communicate to unity but I get this error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'self'"

Here's my code:

```
extern "C"
{
    void _PushTwitter(const char * messageTweet)
    {
        //Check Twitter accessibility and at least one account is setup.
        if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

            SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

            //This is setting the initial text for our share card.
            [tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:messageTweet]];

            //Brings up the little share card with the test we have pre defind. 
            [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {
            //This alreat tells the user that they can't use built in socal interegration and why they can't.
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure you have at least one Twitter account setup and your device is running the latest iOS version" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }

    }
}
```

I get the error on the [self presentViewController...] part.

This was the original code:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    //Each button title we gave to our action sheet is given a tag starting with 0.
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        //Check Twitter accessibility and at least one account is setup.
        if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

            SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

            //This is setting the initial text for our share card.
            [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"veasoftware.com made it easy to intergate Twitter with iOS 6! :D "];

            //Brings up the little share card with the test we have pre defind. 
            [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {
            //This alreat tells the user that they can't use built in socal interegration and why they can't.
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure you have at least one Twitter account setup and your device is using iOS6." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
}
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT/SOLUTION: For anybody interested, I've found a much easier integration on this article (probably the only one out there): http://www.theappguruz.com/unity/share-image-and-text-on-twitter-in-ios-using-native-code/ Works like a charm. I'm running iOS 8, Unity 5, and the latest version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you found is probably part of an objective-c class, where **self** is defined and it points to the current object.

The code that you wrote doesn't seem to be a method of a class, but a global function, which means it doesn't have an object attached.

You should add the code you found to one of the classes Unity defines for you, maybe inside UnityAppController.mm

Comment: Okay thanks done, but then how do I call it from within Unity?